# How to hand out a number my means of a button?

Tags: android, android-studio, button, calculator

I try to program just a pocket calculator app. My first pocket calculators app has functioned perfect. Now I want to extend them while I enter the numbers through buttons. I can create a number from 0 to 9. Now I want to write 33. 
How do I create this?

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.EditText;

import static com.example.taschenrechnerv3.R.id.zahlin;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void my3(View v){ 
EditText zahlin2 = (EditText)findViewById(zahlin); 
zahlin2.setText(String.valueOf("3"));

}

}
```

Comment: you need to append instead setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use counter variable for that like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.EditText;

import static com.example.taschenrechnerv3.R.id.zahlin;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int counter; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
counter=0;

}
public void my3(View v){ 
EditText zahlin2 = (EditText)findViewById(zahlin); 
counter=(counter*10)+3
zahlin2.setText(counter);

}

public void my4(View v){ 
EditText zahlin2 = (EditText)findViewById(zahlin4); 
counter=(counter*10)+4
zahlin2.setText(counter);

}
}
```